# Por qué no me compila la tarea la tarea de compilara sass con gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Estoy tratando de compilar una tarea de sass con gulp pero me sale el error que se muestra en la imagen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwA6b.png